# JS - passing argument into nested argument

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

How does **'cal2(a)(2)'** work in the code below?

```
cal2 = (a) => (b) =>{return a+b}
cal = (a) => { return cal2(a)(2)};
cal(1)
\\ 3
```

Comment: `cal2` is a function that returns another function. By doing `cal2(a)(2)` you are passing `a` to `cal2` and `2` to the function that `cal2` returns.

Comment: Thanks Chris, would you mind tell me the order of the execute?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to rewrite it in more traditional format:

```
cal2 = function(a) {
    retval = function(b) {
        return a + b
    }

    return retval;
}

cal = function(a) {
    return cal2(a)(2);
}
```

This should explain the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Your cal function returns the result of cal2(a)(2). cal2 is a function which returns another function in which you return the sum of the 2 variables that you passed to call2 and and to the anonymous function that it returns. Basically cal2(1) will only return a function but when you add another paranthesis you are are also calling that anonymous function. Here is an example;

```js
const cal2 = (a) => (b) =>{return a+b}
const cal = (a) => { return cal2(a)(2)};
cal(1); // returns 3;

const aFunction = cal2(3); // it becomes a function
console.log(aFunction(2)); // You can call it anytime, logs:5
console.log(cal2(3)(2)); //You directly called the returned function, logs:5
```

Comment: Thanks, Yunus Emre.

Comment: You are welcome Hugo, By the way the order is cal => cal2 => anonymous.